# Provider in different route Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-routes

I wanted to upload a picture inside Firebase Storage when I saw this error :

`The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.`

So I started study what is this Provider and now I understood that I need to include the page that I'm using to upload the picture inside the same route of the ancestor `Provider` of type `Database`.

So I had the issue inside "Registration_form" that is created by "LogInPage" through a Navigator like this :

```
void navigateToRegistrationForm(context) {
  Navigator.push(context,
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Reg_Form();
  }));
  return;
}
```

Now I'm changing the code that is something like :

```
void navigateToRegistrationForm(context) {
  Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => Provider<Database>(
                create: (_) => FirestoreDatabase(),
                builder: (context, child) => Reg_Form(),
              )));
  return;
}
```

But I don't understand what I should pass to the `create` method...I just want to create `Reg_Form`in the right route to call Firebase functions to put the file inside firebase storage so I think that `FirebaseDatabase` isn't what suits my needs.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your issue correctly, you can either move your `ChangeNotifierProvider` for your `Database` class higher up in the widget tree by wrapping your `MaterialApp` like so:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<Database> (
  builder: (context) => Database(),
  child: MaterialApp(...
```

Or just change the `create` in what you provided to

```
create: (_) => Database(),
```

Either way should give you access to the correct Provider/BuildContext in your Registration form with standard `context.read<Database>()...`